# Actors example not compiling

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am trying to run this code to learn actors (using Scala on Eclipse) but it is telling me that values Ping and Pong are not found.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

I installed akka.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

---

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

class Ping(count: int, pong:Actor) extends Actor{ // type int here is not found as well
   def act(){
     var pingsLeft= count-1
     pong! Ping
      while(true){
        receive {
         case Pong =>
           if (pingsLeft % 1000 ==0)
             Console.println("Ping : pong ")
         if (pingsLeft > 0){
           pong ! Ping
           pingsleft -=1
         } else {
          Console.println("Ping : stop")
          pong ! Stop
          exit()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Pong extends Actor {
  def act(){
    var pongCount =0
    while (true){
      receive {
        case Ping =>
          if(pongCount % 1000 ==0)
            Console.println("Pong : ping " + pongCount)
           sender ! Pong
           pongCount = pongCount + 1
        case Stop =>
          Console.println("Pong : stop")
          exit()
      }
    }
  }
 }

 object pingpong extends Application {
  val pong = new Pong
  val ping = new Ping(100000, pong)
  ping.start
  pong.start
}
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, scala actors have been deprecated.  If you are planning on using Actors you should change your example to use actors from akka.actor instead of scala.actor.  You will also need to refactor the code to use the akka conventions as well.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in my comment, you should switch your example over to `Akka`.  Here is a rough approximation of your example refactored to using `Akka`:

```
import akka.actor._

class Ping(count: Int, pong:ActorRef) extends Actor{ // type int here is not found as well
  pong! Ping
  var pingsLeft = count - 1

  def receive = {
    case Pong =>
      if (pingsLeft % 1000 ==0)
        Console.println("Ping : pong ")
      if (pingsLeft > 0){
        pong ! Ping
        pingsLeft -=1
      } else {
        Console.println("Ping : stop")
        pong ! Stop
        context stop self    
    }
  }
}

class Pong extends Actor {
  var pongCount =0

  def receive = {
        case Ping =>
          if(pongCount % 1000 ==0)
            Console.println("Pong : ping " + pongCount)
           sender ! Pong
           pongCount = pongCount + 1
        case Stop =>
          Console.println("Pong : stop")
          exit()    
  }
 }

case object Ping
case object Pong
case object Stop

object pingpong {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("pingpong")
    val pong = system.actorOf(Props[Pong])
    val ping = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Ping], 100000, pong))  
  }

}
```

And he's a slightly refactored version, cleaning up some mutable state and also setting up the   `Pong` instance as a child of the `Ping` instance so that when `Ping` stops, it also automatically stops the `Pong` instance:

```
import akka.actor._

class Ping(count: Int) extends Actor{ // type int here is not found as well
  val pong = context.actorOf(Props[Pong])
  pong! Ping

  def receive = pingReceive(count - 1)

  def pingReceive(pingsLeft:Int):Receive = {
    case Pong =>
      if (pingsLeft % 1000 ==0)
        Console.println("Ping : pong ")
      if (pingsLeft > 0){
        pong ! Ping
        context.become(pingReceive(pingsLeft - 1))
      } 
      else {
        Console.println("Ping : stop")
        context stop self    
      }        
  }
}

class Pong extends Actor {
  override def postStop{
    Console.println("Pong : stop") 
  }

  def receive = pongReceive(0)

  def pongReceive(pongCount:Int):Receive = {
    case Ping =>
      if(pongCount % 1000 ==0) 
        Console.println("Pong : ping " + pongCount)

      sender ! Pong
      context.become(pongReceive(pongCount + 1))        
  }
}

case object Ping
case object Pong

object PingPong {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("pingpong")
    val ping = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[Ping], 100000))  
  }    
}
```